# Is x86_64 IDT shared between CPUs in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, cpu-architecture, interrupt

***TLDR:***

Q1: Does Intel x86_64 architecture has per CPU **idtr**? If so, then should IDT be loaded *N* times, where **N** is the number of CPUs? I mean for each CPU, not for one CPU **N** times.

Q2: I found that IDT is shared between CPUs on x86_64, while comment in Linux says the opposite (x86_64 has per CPU IDT tables), which position is correct?

***Lengthy description***

I'm investigating IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table) setup in Linux and I found such a comment in [arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/58720809f52779dc0f08e53e54b014209d13eebb/arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h#L6):

```c
/*
 * Linux IRQ vector layout.
 *
 * There are 256 IDT entries (per CPU - each entry is 8 bytes) which can
 * be defined by Linux. They are used as a jump table by the CPU when a
 * given vector is triggered - by a CPU-external, CPU-internal or
 * software-triggered event.
 *
 * Linux sets the kernel code address each entry jumps to early during
 * bootup, and never changes them. This is the general layout of the
 * IDT entries:
 *
 *  Vectors   0 ...  31 : system traps and exceptions - hardcoded events
 *  Vectors  32 ... 127 : device interrupts
 *  Vector  128         : legacy int80 syscall interface
 *  Vectors 129 ... LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR-1
 *  Vectors LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR ... 255 : special interrupts
 *
 * 64-bit x86 has per CPU IDT tables, 32-bit has one shared IDT table.
 *
 * This file enumerates the exact layout of them:
 */
```

Layout of IDT is understood, but one line made me confused:

```
64-bit x86 has per CPU IDT tables, 32-bit has one shared IDT table.
```

The reason of confusion is the following: AFAIK "main" (not IVT/early IDT) IDT is loaded at:

```c
void __init idt_setup_apic_and_irq_gates(void)
{
    /* Prepare interrupt gates and idt_descr */
    ...
    /* Map IDT into CPU entry area and reload it. */
    idt_map_in_cea();
    load_idt(&idt_descr);
    ...
}
```

So, looking at `idt_map_in_cea`:

```c
static void __init idt_map_in_cea(void)
{
    /*
     * Set the IDT descriptor to a fixed read-only location in the cpu
     * entry area, so that the "sidt" instruction will not leak the
     * location of the kernel, and to defend the IDT against arbitrary
     * memory write vulnerabilities.
     */
    cea_set_pte(CPU_ENTRY_AREA_RO_IDT_VADDR, __pa_symbol(idt_table),
            PAGE_KERNEL_RO);
    idt_descr.address = CPU_ENTRY_AREA_RO_IDT;
}
```

Here I see IDT is mapped into `CPU_ENTRY_AREA_RO_IDT` which is equal to `fffffe0000000000` (according to [linux virtual memory map](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) this is indeed the start of CPU entry area) and then that one is loaded using `lidt` in `load_idt()` function.

First, I thought that "since this is virtual address there should be different page tables, so there will be different physical instances of IDT", but dumping **idtr** using `sidt` (actually `store_idt` function) gives this virtual address (`fffffe0000000000`) as expected, but walking page tables `for_each_online_cpu` gives the same physical address. Using `gdb/QEMU` I found out that this address is correct and correspond to `idt_table` symbol (actual IDT table that has been loaded after `idt_map_in_cea`). This is actually what made me confused, I can see that IDT is shared between CPUs, is it so or am I missing something?

Also, when I copy the IDT to my own LKM memory and then reload it using `lidt` (actually `load_idt` function) walking page tables `for_each_online_cpu` gives the same LKM address even though I didn't execute `lidt` for each cpu to load new IDT for all CPUs.

***EDIT 1:***

I use `smp_call_function_single` to get IDTR of a special CPU:

```c
static void smp_get_idtr(void *info)
{
    struct desc_ptr *idt_ptr = info;
    store_idt(idt_ptr);
}

static void idtr_per_cpu_show(void)
{
    int cpu;

    for_each_online_cpu(cpu) {
        struct desc_ptr *idt_ptr = kzalloc(...);
        
        /* ... */
        
        smp_call_function_single(cpu, smp_get_idtr, idt_ptr, 1);
        
        /* print address/base */

        kfree(idt_ptr);
    }
}
```

***EDIT 2:***

I found that, I used the same scheme as above to load newly copied IDT, so all CPUs had the same table (Yeah, I'm lazy one who just copy-pasted the function). I fixed that and before reloading I can still see the same physical address of initial IDT, but once I reloaded table with my own copy on say CPU 0 then I have my own IDT's address only for that CPU, others still have initial physical and virtual address (e.g. like below for 4-socket VM):

```
CPU 0:
    base   = 0xffff8b3c484dc000
    limit  = 0xfff
    
    phys   = 0x0x00000001084dc000

CPU 1:
    base   = 0xfffffe0000000000
    limit  = 0xfff

    phys   = 0x0x000000007659b000

CPU 2:
    base   = 0xfffffe0000000000
    limit  = 0xfff

    phys   = 0x0x000000007659b000

CPU 3:
    base   = 0xfffffe0000000000
    limit  = 0xfff

    phys   = 0x0x000000007659b000
```

Comment: As far as I know, each CPU has its own IDTR; I can't really think of how it could work otherwise.  I think that the question here is whether the kernel software chooses to set all of them to point to the same table in memory, or to N different tables.  It sounds like the former is the case for 32-bit kernels.  It's possible that 64-bit kernels *can* have different CPUs point to the same in-memory table, when it so happens that the kernel wants them to use the same one, but with the option also for them to be different.

Comment: I would expect that all CPUs share the same mapping of kernel space, so your last test isn't surprising.  But did you try doing `store_idt` on all CPUs after doing `load_idt` on one of them?  That's where I would expect you'd see the difference.

Comment: @NateEldredge, yeah, I tried that test too, I executed `lidt` on only one CPU and after that `sidt` gave me the same idtr (this is expected since `idtr.base` is virtual address) and the same physical one on ***all*** CPUs (that is weird). I think there are two ways: 1st is comment says about IRQ stacks which are actually per CPU and 2nd is there's some magic about APIC/TSS or so

Comment: How exactly are you using `for_each_online_cpu`?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I updated post. I figured out that each CPU has its own IDTR, but I still can see that initial IDT is shared between CPUs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*IDT IS shared between CPUs*

During initialization phase of secondary CPUs in `start_secondary` there's a call to `cpu_init_exception_handling`:

```c
/*
 * Activate a secondary processor.
 */
static void notrace start_secondary(void *unused)
{
    /* ... */

    cpu_init_exception_handling();

    /* ... */
```

At this moment "main" IDT was set up for CPU 0, but `idt_table` hasn't been changed, so `cpu_init_exception_handling` loads that IDT's address:

```c
/*
 * Setup everything needed to handle exceptions from the IDT, including the IST
 * exceptions which use paranoid_entry().
 */
void cpu_init_exception_handling(void)
{
    /* ... */

    /* Finally load the IDT */
    load_current_idt();
}
```

which expands to:

```c
void load_current_idt(void)
{
    /* ... */

    load_idt(&idt_descr);
}
```

and since CPU 0 initialization `idt_descr` wasn't changed and IDT is not writable it loads the same IDT for the rest of CPUs.